# Custom height not being applied to UITableView Prototype Cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I am building a table view scene and I have defined a custom height for the prototype cell. I have created a file for the custom cell and added an image and two labels via IBOutlets in that file. I have wired the table view and the table is calling in the information, however the height is not being applied. Here is my syntax for the cell class and the cellForRow method.

TableView Article Object:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FeedItem {

    var feedItemTitle: String
    var feedItemImage: UIImage
    var feedItemExcerpt: String = "Lorem ipsum dolor amet flexitarian art party skateboard, ethical pop-up drinking vinegar readymade humblebrag hot chicken. Retro kogi quinoa..."
    var feedItemLike: UIImage
    var feedItemComment: UIImage

    init(feedItemTitle: String, feedItemImage: UIImage, feedItemLike: UIImage, feedItemComment: UIImage) {
        self.feedItemTitle = feedItemTitle
        self.feedItemImage = feedItemImage
        self.feedItemLike = feedItemLike
        self.feedItemComment = feedItemComment
    }

}
```

TableView Cell:

```
import UIKit

class FeedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var articleImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var articleTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var articleExcerptLabel: UILabel!

}
```

TableView Extension:

```
extension NewFeedViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return articlesArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Article Cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell
        cell.articleImageView.image = articlesArray[indexPath.row].feedItemImage
        cell.articleTitleLabel.text = articlesArray[indexPath.row].feedItemTitle
        cell.articleExcerptLabel.text = articlesArray[indexPath.row].feedItemExcerpt
        return cell
    }

}
```

Here is a screenshot of what the table view looks like when the app is ran:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the Prototype cell and the Size Inspector in Xcode:

[image]

Comment: Add this `self.table.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 ;
self.table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly specify row height in delegate method. Just like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 100.0;//Choose your custom row height
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Use this property

```
self.table.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 
self.table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Or even you can use delegates also

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `viewDidLoad()` use
 `tableView.rowHeight = 400`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

1- use dynamic tableView like that in viewDidLoad

```
 tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400;

 tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

2- don't implement hightforCellAtIndexpath

3- adjust constraints properly in cell xib from top to bottom

4- regarding the collectionview , imageView and reply section give them all a height constraint of zero initially then, hook the height constraint for each on as IBOulet and change it's constant value in **cellForRowAtIndexpath** according to the current item manage the hide/show by changing the corresponding constant value of the constraint

5- before return cell do this

```
 cell.layoutSubviews()

 cell.layoutIfNeeded()

 return cell
```

so cell can be relayouted to reflect the change of it's subviews's constraints

Answer (score 0):

Use `Delegate` method with `heightForRowAt`  of you `UITableView` -

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 130.0;
}
```